# Matching Regular Expression of Emoticons

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a regex in Ruby to match a huge list of emoticons

```
/\|?>?[:*;Xx8=<(%)D]-?'?,?o?\_^?[-DOo0S*Ppb3c:;\/\\|)(}{\]><]\)?/
```

But it doesnt match a few emoticons like

```
:'-(
```

and

```
:*(
```

The link with my set of matching emoticons is http://rubular.com/r/1vnWEvN76v

How do I match the unmatched ones ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `r":'-\("` for first example and `r":\*\("` for second . and you can add them with pipe (`|`) to your regex ! but its depend on what you want to be matched with your `regex` , also you can add them after other regexes or use & or ..

Note that `(` and `*` are regex symbols and you need `\` before them !

in this case for your regex you just need to add `|\(` end of your regex:

```
\|?>?[:*;Xx8=<(%)D]-?'?,?o?\_^?[-DOo0S*Ppb3c:;\/\\|)(}{\]><]\)?|\(
```

Comment: Thanks for advice! But I'm a n00b in regex. can you give me the full regex please???

Comment: your welcome , i edit the answer , so can you tell me that emoticons you want to match are those amount other text or came separately ?

Comment: dude, i gave this 
    r":\*\("|r":'-\("|\|?>?[:*;Xx8=<(%)D]-?'?,?o?\_^?[-DOo0S*Ppb3c:;\/\\|)(}{\]><]\) 

and it didnt work

Comment: why you add them in `()` ? you must add them end of regex ! i will add complete answer now  !

Comment: It didnt match. note - Im using ruby 1.8.7 to match

Comment: give me 1min ! now do it!

Comment: you just need to add `|\(` to end of your regex